# Getting Http status 400 in api 23 and below

Tags: android, httpconnection

I have to call one Rest API of GET request.

When I used emulator of API 24 it working fine. but same code on my phone i.e API 23 and API 18 it give 400 status i.e. bad request.

```
 URL url = new URL(voids[0]);
        Log.i("url", voids[0]);
        //URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "REST");
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*//*");
        con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        con.setReadTimeout(10000);
        con.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
       responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Sending get request : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response code : " + responseCode);
        // Reading response from input Stream
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String output;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(output);
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Url : [http://milk.gall5.com/api/SalePunch?CustomerID=1&Model={"CustomerID":"1","lstSalesPunchDetail":[{"ListManufacturer":[{"ManufactureID":1,"ManufacturerName":"Amul","One":40,"OneByFour":10,"OneByTwo":20,"QtyOne":0,"QtyOneByFour":23,"QtyOneByTwo":330,"visibilityOne":true,"visibilityOneByFour":true,"visibilityOneByTwo":true}],"ProductId":2,"ProductName":"Ton Milk"}]}](http://%20http://milk.gall5.com/api/SalePunch?CustomerID=1&Model=%7B%22CustomerID%22:%221%22,%22lstSalesPunchDetail%22:[%7B%22ListManufacturer%22:[%7B%22ManufactureID%22:1,%22ManufacturerName%22:%22Amul%22,%22One%22:40,%22OneByFour%22:10,%22OneByTwo%22:20,%22QtyOne%22:0,%22QtyOneByFour%22:23,%22QtyOneByTwo%22:330,%22visibilityOne%22:true,%22visibilityOneByFour%22:true,%22visibilityOneByTwo%22:true%7D],%22ProductId%22:2,%22ProductName%22:%22Ton%20Milk%22%7D]%7D)

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode the `Model` parameter of your URL first.
You can do that with the `URLEncoder.encode()` method